# How to add an chrome extension using crosh

Tags: chromebook

i'm trying to find out how to add the TI connect CE extension to my school chromebook, but i'm using crosh to do so since every other method is blocked. Any help is appreciated!

I tried to search ways to do it on chrome but they were all for linux and windows shell

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to do with crosh, as it explicitly does not have that functionality. You could:

- try to run the windows version of the app using emulation in the chromeOS built-in linux emulator if it's unlocked (it would be very slow through)
- try to completely unlock your chromebook by making a usb recovery tool for it and restarting it so you have root acces etc. You school might severely punish you for that tho.

I also tried to install it in the Kivi Browser android app (you can installl standard chrome extensions on it) and change the user agent so I could theoretically trick the webstore that my kivi browser is chromeOS browser, but it didn't work. Maybe you will have  more luck with it tho.